# Output raster of rasterio.mask doesn't match CRS of input

Tags: python, coordinate-system, rasterio, masking

I'm trying to mask a raster with population data with my area of interest. I reprojected the original population raster according to the AOI's crs, but after masking and writing the new file, the crs is set back to the original's crs, even though both inputs have the right crs (which is 32644). Can anyone point me to my mistake? I know I could reproject again, but there has to be a simpler way, right?

```
raster_crs = CRS(AOI.crs).to_epsg()
```

## open original raster

```
with rio.open(pop_path, mode='r+') as pop:
    transform, width, height = calculate_default_transform(
        pop.crs, raster_crs, pop.width, pop.height, *pop.bounds)
    kwargs = pop.meta.copy()
    kwargs.update({
        'crs': raster_crs,
        'transform': transform,
        'width': width,
        'height': height
    })

CRS(pop.crs).to_epsg()
```

> 4326

## reproject original raster to AOI's crs

```
    with rio.open(pop_proj_tif, 'w', **kwargs) as pop_proj:
        for i in range(1, pop.count + 1):
            reproject(
                source=rio.band(pop, i),
                destination=rio.band(pop_proj, i),
                pop_transform=pop.transform,
                pop_crs=pop.crs,
                pop_proj_transform=transform,
                pop_proj_crs=raster_crs,
                resampling=Resampling.nearest)

CRS(AOI.crs).to_epsg()
```

> 32644

```
CRS(pop_proj.crs).to_epsg()
```

> 32644

## mask reprojected raster with AOI

```
with rio.open(pop_proj_tif) as pop_proj:
    pop_out_image, out_transform = rio.mask.mask(pop_proj, AOI.geometry, crop=True)
    pop_out_meta = pop.meta

pop_out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                 "height": pop_out_image.shape[1],
                 "width": pop_out_image.shape[2],
                     "transform": out_transform})
```

## writing masked raster gives wrong CRS

```
    with rio.open(pop_proj_clip_tif, "w", **pop_out_meta) as pop_dest:
        pop_dest.write(pop_out_image)

CRS(pop_dest.crs).to_epsg()
```

> 4326

Comment: Is the projected raster saved on disk before you open it at stage "mask reprojected raster with AOI"?

Comment: @user30184 that's what the `with rio.open(pop_proj_tif, 'w', **kwargs) as pop_proj:` statement does,  then the `reproject` writes directly to the output band `destination=rio.band(pop_proj, i)`.

Comment: Could you still check what is the CRS when you do `with rio.open(pop_proj_tif) as pop_proj:` at stage "mask reprojected raster with AOI"?

Comment: Please provide a actual runnable code sample, including `import`s (so we can just substitute our data). Your code fails immediately as CRS, AOI, rio are not defined.

Comment: @user2856 I was wondering how to deal with this and couldn't find an answer in the help section. The problem is that AOI itself is a long script, which I thought would be redundant. I suppose you'd just replace vector and raster with some samples...nevertheless I should have added the imports. Will do next time, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are copying `pop.meta` instead of `pop_proj.meta`.

Replace:

```
# mask reprojected raster with AOI
with rio.open(pop_proj_tif) as pop_proj:
    pop_out_image, out_transform = rio.mask.mask(pop_proj, AOI.geometry, crop=True)
    pop_out_meta = pop.meta #<== wrong
```

With:

```
# mask reprojected raster with AOI
with rio.open(pop_proj_tif) as pop_proj:
    pop_out_image, out_transform = rio.mask.mask(pop_proj, AOI.geometry, crop=True)
    pop_out_meta = pop_proj.meta #<== this works
```

Also the `reproject` function signature doesn't have the following arguments - `pop_transform`, `pop_crs`, `pop_proj_transform` or `pop_proj_crs` and it's only a lucky accident that you didn't get a `TypeError: reproject() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pop_transform'` as the reproject function accepts a `**kwargs` argument for any additional arguments that should be passed to both the image to image transformer `GDALCreateGenImgProjTransformer2()` (for example, MAX_GCP_ORDER=2) and the `GDALWarpOptions` (for example, INIT_DEST=NO_DATA).

Use the following instead:

```
        reproject(
            source=rio.band(pop, i),
            destination=rio.band(pop_proj, i),
            src_transform=pop.transform,
            src_crs=pop.crs,
            dst_transform=transform,
            dst_crs=raster_crs,
            resampling=Resampling.nearest)
```

Or just drop them completely as they will be read from the source and dest bands anyway:

```
        reproject(
            source=rio.band(pop, i),
            destination=rio.band(pop_proj, i),
            resampling=Resampling.nearest)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much. That saves me a lot of time.